# Polylang - не выводятся все языки в select

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, polylang

Использую плагин Polylang. У меня три языка En Ru Uk. Для вывода выпадающего списка использую такой вот код.

```
<?php 
    pll_the_languages( ['dropdown' => 3 ] );
?>
```

В итоге выводится select с таким html с одним только активным языком. Посетитель не может выбрать язык страницы.

```
<select name="lang_choice_3" id="lang_choice_3" class="pll-switcher-select">
    <option value="http://propertypartners/?lang=ru" lang="ru-RU">Русский</option>
</select>
```

Нужно в шапке сайта вывести выпадающий список выбора языка страницы. Как это сделать с плагином Polylang ?

Answer (score 0):

> Для вывода выпадающего списка использую такой вот код.

насколько я помню виждет выбора языка - штатная функция плагина.

> Посетитель не может выбрать язык страницы.

Такое бывает если плагин настроен на "не показывать непереведённые страницы" (как-то так называется настройка).